# CVS/repository for Altium

Tags: altium

I am trying to build a versioning system/repository for my Altium design project/files. Can anyone recommend a versioning system(preferably open source) for such files?

Comment: Doesn't Altium have built in version control?

Comment: I dont want to use Altium's bulit in CVS.

Comment: [This question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115790/how-to-use-altium-svn-version-control-with-bitbucket?rq=1) suggests that Altium supports Subversion (SVN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently use GIT with Altium to back up my files. I watched this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXSMZMNnvww video which helped me set it up. It's not an exact Altium to GIT but it does give you the general steps to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I use SVN, but not within Altium, I just check in the SchDoc, PcbDoc, OutJob, and PrjPCB. The nice thing is that the Altium version control tools (like diff) work just fine, and I didn't ever have to configure Altium for version control - it just saw that the files were under SVN and knew how to handle them. It works quite well, especially with the Altium files. I also tag releases when I send them off to manufacturing.

Answer (score 1):

[Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) is one popular free open-source choice that is scalable (it works with distributed workflows).

Comment: but is it smooth with schematics and layout as I thought(I may be wrong) that GIT is text based while the schemas and PCB files are binary.
Also, do you have any tutorials for a GIT based CVS system for Altium files specificaly please. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: It works okay. Merging binary files from multiple change sources makes no sense so that part won't work, obviously. See the answer from @ShannonHenstorf for a tutorial.